# change mysql result number -> word

Tags: php, mysql

I get from mysql result like 1 or 2. But I want that 1 shows XXX and 2 shows YYY.

Ive tryed already this but it doesnt work

```
$cat = array(
    '1' => 'XXX',
    '2' => 'YYY'
);
```

Now where I got a problem:

```
<?PHP foreach($cat AS echo $getItem["type"]; == $aValue) {
    echo'<p>Category: '.$aValue.'</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

getitem["type"] will display a 1 or 2 but only get white page

Comment: White page means some fatal error, in your case it is syntax error in `$cat AS echo $getItem["type"]; == $aValue`.

Comment: Indeed you may want to configure your php.ini with display_errors = On; display_startup_errors = On   so you can see those nasty parser errors instead off an even more nastier white page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why simply not:

```
echo 'Category: '.$cat[$getItem["type"]];
```

?